# Prevent a program from opening your program

Tags: c++, vb.net, c#-4.0, wpf-4.0

Okay let's say we don't want hexworkshop or hxd from opening an executable that I made. How would I go about doing that? Is it even possible? Basically what I am looking for is preventing other programs from being able to open my program without the need of my program being open at the time.

Note: I do know how to kill processes but that only works when the program is currently open. what I want is it to prevent programs from being able to open/read the .exe even when the program isn't being run.

Comment: What happens when `explorer.exe` can't open your application?

Comment: Read up on protection from reverse engineering. There's a lot of techniques for that, but preventing file opening is not one of them; it's not possible.

Comment: Not quite answering your question, but if you want to protect the IP in your executable, your only real path is to never drop the executable on a machine you don't control. Serve up critical logic, or the whole app, from your servers.

Comment: What about padding the beginning of the executable with 1024 null bytes? Then you could write a launcher that removes the padding and executes it when given a specific command line key/option. Or, your launcher could copy the file to a temp directory, skipping the first 1024 bytes, then executing that. Then your launcher could monitor the process and delete the temp file when it exits. Just a thought anyway.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead
that is a good idea. basically reverse engineering is what I am working to prevent. there is a program called de4dot. I want to just prevent it from opening my program. since that program removes all my encryptions, etc. if you can help that would be amazing as I am currently trying to prevent my program from noobs getting it. I can stop IDA and others from attaching to my program which is enough to stop most people but all the noobs that use de4dot will get my source.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta
I tried looking up methods to keep them from getting the real .exe and have it run remotely but that didn't really work out as I wanted. would of been seen as a hacking tool by anti-viruses.

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev
well there should be a way as a guy I know did it for his computer chips he makes but he won't give any info out on how he did it. might not work for executables anyway and only work for computer chips idk. all I know is he did it from a custom class he made not using system or anything else.

Comment: Yeah, remote code execution would definitely be viewed in a poor light by AV tools. That's not what I was suggesting, though. Instead, build and maintain a remote service that produces an output, based on inputs that your client-resident executable feeds it. Or just build a web app.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta
that could be done. thanks. a web app is no-go as the animations I am using look ugly on a web app and doesn't allow drag n drop of an image to change the background. the application I am making is MVVM with tons of custom controls. that look real nice running but not so much on web apps. as I have already tried those out and it looked real ugly.

Comment: The only answer to this question is: Don't put your program on the machine in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply not possible to prevent windows applications from opening any kind of file unless windows itself prevents you from doing so.  e.g. through file permissions etc.  This is next to useless.  i.e. If you can execute the application you can open and read it because you need to be able to do that to run it.  Basically your program is a file and the OS treats it that way.

---

Since your goal is to prevent pirating or stealing your software one option that I've heard done is to put regular program validity checks into the code.

Most hackers will only circumvent early checks to get it to run up, but if your checks are scattered throughout the code you make it very much much harder for a hacker to circumvent these.

Another option is to use a dongle.  As I understand it your program is encrypted and decrypted by software or by the dongle as it runs.  However, at some point it's in memory so a memory dump will get the software.

The best you can do is make it very hard to steel your code.  But it's not impossible.

The ultimate for software that can't be easily stolen is software that doesn't run on your PC. e.g. web based services.

By the way, software that self destructs or wipes the HDD as you describe in the comments may well be illegal in most countries.

Comment: sorry to say but it is possible. I know a guy that makes computer chips that he sells for 10k (forgot what the guy made them for. but he made the feature I want in them. but his wipes the HDD's if you attempt it.) everything is possible just this type of thing not many actually know. the function to do it should be in system somewhere. just not sure where. thanks anyway.

Comment: You're changing the story a bit, @Lorance. Given a machine you *do* control (enough to install hardware on it!), lots of things are possible.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Not quite to this extent on a Windows machine though.. even if you do own it :P

Comment: @Simon: well, where Lorance says "computer chip", I imagine a VMM running Windows in a VM. Not foolproof (there's malware that can break out of a VM, now), but effective.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta
yeah I am not sure how the guy got it to work. but with enough permissions anything is possible

Comment: @Michael Petrotta
what I was wondering is if I could make my program ask for the permissions? and then if they say yes then it makes it so only approved programs can open my program. meaning all the hacking ones I can filter out. just something I am thinking of anyway. and if they disagree then it removes the program from their pc and creates a registry with their choice so the program remembers their choice.

Comment: @Lorance, if the user is not a member of the Windows Administrators group, you can write your executable to a location that the user doesn't have access to. But you still have to deliver the executable to the machine somehow, and the user who downloads it has, by definition, full access to the executable. And, of course, they can simply pull the drive and mount it under a different OS to get full access. And if the user's an admin, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: And on and on. Once you deliver the bits to the user, on a medium that you don't control, it's too late. And most solutions that allow you to *retain* control end up looking an awful lot like rootkits.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta
ah so not really possible. guess the only other method is remote service app. any tutorials or guides on how to do that? kinda a noob at that. I only really been making web apps or apps that can are executed on the clients pc and clients could easily crack and steal the source.

Comment: Lorance. My guess is your friend probably makes some sort of encryption key device to protect executables.  10k sounds rather expensive!  In any case, this still doesn't stop someone from opening up the file with a hex editor.  But, if the exe is encrypted it makes it hard to know what it's really doing.

Comment: @Lorance: really depends on what you want to do. Since you seem to have a Microsoft background, you may find [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/?fb=en-us) interesting.

Comment: @Matt
For hex editing, what I want to stop is them hexing out my protections and then using de4dot (I have done so before on an app I made and it worked. so I want to prevent that from happening) and the chip he made is being used in machines that make money (forgot the d**n name of it) what his chip does is save them millions of dollars in case of an error (since before they used his chip it would ruin all the bills being made)

Comment: @Michael Petrotta
Thanks I will check that out. Right now there are too many noobs that get a program that is used to remove protections and use that tool to steal source and claim they made it themselves. I am working on an program that I don't want people to steal. I mean yeah I will admit it will get cracked no matter what I do really but I want to make it as hard as possible so only the real professionals will be able to crack it and no noobs.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to figure out when an application was last run by configuring audit process tracking in Windows. The following links might get you started:

> [Audit process tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775520%28WS.10%29.aspx)
>
> [How can I track what programs come and go on my machine?](http://ask-leo.com/how_can_i_track_what_programs_come_and_go_on_my_machine.html)

The process tracking will create entries in the Windows event log which you can then access using C++, C# &/or VB.Net.

**This way you can poll to see if a program is running (that clashes with yours) and simply quit your application.**

**Edit:**

> Note: I do know how to kill processes but that only works when the
> program is currently open. what I want is it to prevent programs from
> being able to open/read the .exe even when the program isn't being run

You would need to use a tool such as [`Salamander protector`](http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/protector.html) - .NET protector is the a technology that offers real protection for your .NET code. In contrast to an obfuscator that makes decompilation more difficult by symbol renaming, RemoteSofts protector completely stops MSIL disassembly and decompilation . With this tool, you are assured that no one will be able to steal your source code. With this tool, you no longer need to worry about one headache of Microsoft .NET platform - decompilation.

Comment: *"our protector completely stops MSIL disassembly and decompilation"* - Is this really your tool, Jeremy? The marketing is a little strong here.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Yeah that did sound a little strong, I fixed it up and I dont work for RemoteSoft.